# node index.js not working like error express

Tags: node.js, reactjs

ok so here is what i got on cli
anyone how to fix this
i have tried
npm cache clean but its not working

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\iftkh\Backend\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\iftkh\Backend\index.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\iftkh\\Backend\\index.js' ]
```

Comment: Make sure you are in the right directory and you have installed express correctly.

Comment: hasibur i put in the same dir as in my react file

Comment: i even cleared all installed npm's and it still didnt work

Comment: you can't directly use express in your react app unless you configure webpack to load commonJS.

Comment: separate your react and node js app in different directories. I hope the error will disipear

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install express correctly, or maybe didn't required it

Comment: any ideas how bcz what i did was npm install express

Comment: Post your express config

Comment: Where is that I can give you the whole folder.like I'm a newbie to all of this so idk everything

Comment: I think you are using nodejs with react app as a customer server, if so, share any codee related to the node js part

Answer (score 0):

could someone solve the problem? Have similar one and can't understand it why!
everything is installed.

```
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.18.1",
  "mysql": "^2.18.1"
}
}
```

Comment: i spent a lot of time for this turns out in the docs you have to make sure that your react native is compatible with each other . I.E your react version should be 17.02 and the stuff will be intercompatible then run yarn and DO NOT INSTALL LATEST PACKAGES THEY ARE SERIOUSLY BUGGED

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32239999)